# how to grab specific columns from multiple data.frame and save it as a new data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-binding, tidyverse, reshape

I have the following example `data.frame` which contains multiple variables (i.e., A,B,C).

```
set.seed(123)

D1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2001-01-10"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(10,1,5),
                 B = runif(10,3,6),
                 C = runif(10,2,5))
D2 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2001-01-10"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(10,1,5),
                 B = runif(10,3,6),
                 C = runif(10,2,5))
D3 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2001-01-10"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(10,1,5), 
                 B = runif(10,3,6), 
                 C = runif(10,2,5))
```

**Target**
I want to grab each variables from all the `data.frame` and save it as a new `data.frame` with the name set as `Variable` and column names set as `data.frame+variable` like below

```
A <- data.frame(Date, D1A,D2A,D3A)
B <- data.frame(Date,D1B,D2B,D3B)
C <- data.frame(Date,D1C,D2C,D3C)
```

I would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the datasets in a `list` (without the first column 'Date'), `transpose`, then loop over the `list` with `map`, bind the 'Date' column  in each of those datasets (it is better to keep it as a `list`, but if needed use `list2env` to create the objects in the global env)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list(D1 = D1[-1], D2 = D2[-1], D3 = D3[-1]) %>%
     transpose %>%
     map(~ bind_cols(D1['Date'], .)) %>%
    list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

-check the objects A, B, C created

```
head(A, 2)
#        Date       D1       D2       D3
#1 2001-01-01 2.150310 4.852097 3.660461
#2 2001-01-02 4.153221 4.609196 1.379363
head(B, 2)
#        Date       D1       D2       D3
#1 2001-01-01 5.870500 3.428400 5.263425
#2 2001-01-02 4.360002 4.243639 4.887663
head(C, 2)
#        Date       D1       D2       D3
#1 2001-01-01 4.668618 2.137494 2.730858
#2 2001-01-02 4.078410 3.326600 4.004167
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, is there away to just grab all the `data.frame` within the `Global Environment` workspace while converting to `list` instead specifying their names? I have many `data.frame` with strange names so it would be difficult to type their names one by one.

Comment: @Hydro Yes, if you have all the dataset names that have a pattern `D1`, `D2`, etc. `mget(ls(pattern = '^D\\d+$')) %>% map(~ .x[-1]) %>% transpose %>..`

Comment: the names are like  `"comb_1134887_avg_data.csv" "comb_1134570_avg_data.csv" "comb_1127495_avg_data.csv" "comb_1127543_avg_data.csv"`. These are just a few, there are many more like this. I am reading multiple `csv` files from the directory which is why the `.csv` is added to each `data.frame` at the end.

Comment: @Hydro Are these object names or file names that needs to be read?

Comment: I am reading a large number of `csv` files from a directory `temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")` and then 
`for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i])[,c(1,2,3,5,8,10)])`.  The class option says they are `data.frames` . Here is the what i get  `class(comb_1002652_avg_data.csv)'
'[1] "data.frame"`

Comment: @Hydro In that case you can change the earlier line to `mget(ls(pattern = "^comb_\\d+_avg_data\\.csv$")) %>% map(~ .x[-1]) %>% transpose`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^D\\d+"))
list2env(
  sapply(
    names(lst[[1]])[-1],
    function(x) {
      cbind(
        lst[[1]]["Date"],
        list2DF(lapply(lst, `[[`, x))
      )
    },
    USE.NAMES = TRUE,
    simplify = FALSE
  ),
  envir = .GlobalEnv
)
```